# React native iOS build No such module 'ExpoModulesCore'

Tags: react-native

My React native project build and run from android project. But xCode don't build ios project. It gives error 'No such module 'ExpoModulesCore'. I am try on new project without not install any third party package. Give same error.

react-native info output:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.1
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
    Memory: 705.53 MB / 24.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.22.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.0.1, iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3 Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3
    Xcode: 13.1/13A1030d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 16.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: Try ```nvm unalias default``` if this does not work try using node 14.x.x